I have a component using Popover from shadcn/ui. When I try to testing it with Playwright the locator can´t found the id, how can I resolve?
I have a component using Popover from shadcn/ui. When I try to testing it with Playwright the locator can´t found the id into the Input. I am using React ts. This is a fragment from my component:
 <div className="grid grid-cols-3 items-center gap-4">
              <Label htmlFor="name">Name</Label>
              <Input
                id="name"
                className="col-span-2 h-8"
                value={section}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const newName = e.target.value
                  setSection(newName)
                }}
              />

and this is my spec:
test.describe('CaptureIdPopover Component', () =\> {
    let page: any;
    
    test.beforeEach(async ({ mount, page: p }) => {
        page = p;
        const mockValues = {
        section: 'Test Section',
        setSection: (value: string) => {},
        frameLength: 10,
        setFrameLength: (value: number) => {},
        additionalInfo: 'Test Comments',
        setAdditionalInfo: (value: string) => {},
       };
    
       await mount(
        <MockCameraControlProvider mockValues={mockValues}>
            <CaptureIdPopover/>
        </MockCameraControlProvider>
       );
    })
    
    test('Should render initial values', async () => {
       const nameInput = page.locator('#name');
       await expect(nameInput).toHaveText('Test Section')
    
       const lengthInput = page.locator('#length');
       await expect(lengthInput).toHaveText('15');
    
       const commentsInput = page.locator('#comments');
       await expect(commentsInput).toHaveText('Test Comments')
    })
})

I receive this:

Error: Timed out 5000ms waiting for expect(locator).toHaveText(expected)
Locator: locator('#name')
Expected string: "Test Section"
Received: <element(s) not found>
Call log:

expect.toHaveText with timeout 5000ms
waiting for locator('#name')


31 |  
32 |        const nameInput = page.locator('#name');

33 |        await expect(nameInput).toHaveText('Test Section');
   |                                ^
34 |
35 |        const lengthInput = page.locator('#length');
36 |        await expect(lengthInput).toHaveText('15');


Can you add your rendered html after mounting? console.log(await page.locator("body").innerHTML());
